# How do you store time interval property in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

I wonder whether you can store time interval as property in neo4j, similar to postgresql interval data type. I want to store something like person experience which can range from few months to years. If there is no such data type in neo4j then how do you store this kind of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Duration](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/temporal/#cypher-temporal-durations) datatype:

> Cypher has built-in support for handling temporal values, and the
> underlying database supports storing these temporal values as
> properties on nodes and relationships.

```
RETURN duration.between(date('2020-01-01'), date.realtime()) AS `experience`
```

An example setting properties:

```
CREATE(p:Person)
SET p.name='John Doe',
    p.startDate = date("2020-01-01");

MATCH(p:Person)
WHERE p.name='John Doe'
    SET p.exp = duration.between(p.startDate, date.realtime())
RETURN p
```

I don't recommend this approach as the experience value would be accurate only on the day it was created/updated. It is better to calculate such values on the fly, either using the database or the application layer as opposed to hard-coding it in the DB.

Cypher example for the above node would be:

```
MATCH(p:Person)
WHERE p.name='John Doe' 
RETURN p.name AS `Name`,p.startDate as `Start Date`, duration.between(p.startDate, date.realtime()) AS `experience`
```